# How to pour concrete for curved walkway to prevent cracking?

Tags: concrete, sidewalk

The front edge of my home slab is about 37 feet from the street. There is a 12*4  feet landing pad next to street and a  7*4  area next to front door.  Originally there was a 33*4 rectangular walkway connecting the two. It has been removed and I want to rebuild a walkway in its place.

I am wondering if a curved walkway design resembling a tall trapezoid with curved sides and a wide base close  to 12 feet and a narrow top  close to 5 foot will be practical and good looking.

In particular I am concerned if the curved design is more prone to cracking and what to do to minimize it.  How are spacers and rebars are to be placed?

[image]

Comment: Mesh top and bottom (if thick enough) and pour it in squarish shapes with movement joints between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curved concrete drives and walkways are no more likely to crack than rectangular. I have a semi circular drive and a curved walk. The drive foundation was well packed and it has 1/2 rebar on roughly 18' centers ( we had some left over from the house) , it has handled 10,000+ lb. trucks, no problem . The walk, not so well packed and used only mesh : It has hairline cracks at some decorative brick inlays. So with good preparation and rebar you can make any shape you want.